# About Rsform submission

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a claim form built with RSform.
I need to add 3 informations before validation so I used 3 hiddens fields.
now I need that every user can edit only the field that glows belongs.
For exemple :
field number 1 mut be edit only by user 1
field number 2 mut be edit only by user 2
field number 3 mut be edit only by user 3

Thks

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide code that you have or options that you tried. It would be easier for community to help you.

Comment: You might want to post on https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions instead